# -Wformat-nonliteral and string constants

Tags: c, gcc, printf, compiler-warnings, string-literals

In our code we have some calls to printf-like functions where the format string comes from a named literal:

```
static const char fmt[] = "File read error at %08X";
[...]
qsnprintf(errmsg, sizeof(errmsg), fmt, file_offset);
```

With `-Wformat=2` this produces a warning:

"warning: format not a string literal, argument types not checked [-Wformat-nonliteral]"

Although I don't really understand what's the issue with the original code, I was able to "fix" it like this:

```
static const char * const fmt = "File read error at %08X";
```

However, in a few cases we have an array of format strings, e.g.:

```
  static const char *const rmsg[] =
  {
    NULL,
    "Unknown relocation type 0x%X for symbol \"%s\"",
    "Unimplemented relocation type 0x%X for symbol \"%s\"",
    "Untested relocation type 0x%X for symbol \"%s\"",
    "Relocation to invalid symbol",
  };

  qsnprintf(relerr, sizeof(relerr), rmsg[errnum], type, sym_name);
```

This produces the same warning but I was unable to find a way to make GCC happy here. Do I have to convert this to a switch and several qsnprintf calls?

Comment: Switch cases would at least have the advantage that you can have different argument lists for each case and that you could change one message without risking to break the others. And you can catch illegal `errnum` values. In your example, even if the compiler would check all array entries, you'd have one string without format specifiers and one `NULL`.

Comment: `errnum` values are checked elsewhere, so that's not the issue here.

Comment: Change to `switch` or disable warning for this call.